# Bash script file modification dependency check

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, build

I'm trying to do a simple check in a bash build script to check if the built file XML is newer than the component xml files in a directory.

So basically I have a src/ directory with 10 XML files and a final.xml that is built from those files.

What would be a simple way to check the modification time of the final.xml to ensure it is older than the files in src/.

Something similiar to ANT's

```
    <uptodate property="xml.build.notRequired" targetfile="${final.xml}">
        <srcfiles dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.xml" />
    </uptodate>
```

Or the basic functionality of a Make file (but I'd rather just do it in the script than add Make/ANT as a dependency).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find src -type f | while read filename; do
    if [ "$filename" -nt "final.xml" ]; then
        echo "Oh noes, final.xml is out of date..."
    fi
done
```

Comment: The key here is the test operator `-nt` (for newer than); there is the analogous `-ot` (older than) test too.  These compare the two files on either side, determining whether the RHS is newer than (older than) the one on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

```
find src -newer src/final.xml -print
```

will print all files what are "newer" as final.xml

or

```
n=$(find src -newer src/final.xml | grep -c '.') && echo Here is $n newer files
```

will do `echo` only when here is ANY newer file, otherwise the echo will be not executed